# Wordpress wp_add_inline_style unable to give hex colors?

Tags: php, css

When i am trying to add hex color its crossed out in frontend and if i add color directly i.e.  black or white it works ..how can i fix this issue.

**This one does not work**

```
     function my_styles_method() {
wp_enqueue_style(
    'custom-style',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_script.css'
);
    $color = #FF0000 ;
    $custom_css = "
            .mycolor{
                    background: {$color};
            }";
    wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
```

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' );
?>

**But this one works**

```
   function my_styles_method() {
wp_enqueue_style(
    'custom-style',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_script.css'
);
    $color = black;
    $custom_css = "
            .mycolor{
                    background: {$color};
            }";
    wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $custom_css );
```

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' );
?>

Comment: Both the codes are identical.. Am I missing something?

Comment: sorry my mistake there is difference in $color value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the variables correctly. The values are strings so need to be in quotes:

```
$color = #FF0000 ;
```

Needs to be

```
$color = '#FF0000';
```